How to show this function is a graph of another function?
I learn mathematics by myself and have no tutor or professor to check on my work, so I wish to check if my resolution to this problem is adequate.
This exercise is from A Course on Analysis vol. II, Elon Lages Lima, and goes as follows: 
Let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}^2; f(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ be a $C^k (k\geq 1)$ path with $x'(t) \ne 0$ for all $t \in I$. Show $f(I)$ is the graph of a $C^k$ differentiable function $\xi: J \to \mathbb{R}$.
Here is my attempt at it:
Writing $x(I) = J$, because $x'(t) \ne 0 \forall t \in I$ and, $x \in C^k (k\geq 1), x(t)$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image and therefore there has a $C^k$ differentiable inverse $x^{-1}: J \to I$. We might treat it as a change of coordinates in $\mathbb{R}$. Then  $f \circ x^{-1}: J \to \mathbb{R}^2; (f \circ x^{-1})(t) = (t, (y \circ x^{-1})(t))$ is the graph of the differentiable $C^k$ function $\xi = y \circ x^{-1}$.
